# Is classical projective geometry, or a theory of the real projective plane, complete?

Tags: logic, projective-geometry, foundations

Essentially the title.

Tarski's Euclidean geometry is complete. Is the same true of a theory of the real projective plane (as an example of a model of the theory I am interested in: take the extended Euclidean plane with opposing points at infinity identified)?

I don't have a reference for the real projective plane that considers this. Using von Staudt's throws (würfs) one can define a (maybe just a fragment of) arithmetic within the real projective plane. Is this arithmetic sufficiently strong such that Godel's incompleteness theorem applies?

Comment: Wouldn't throws define arithmetic of *real* numbers, not of natural numbers?

Comment: I am unsure whether they define an arithmetic of real numbers, on account of the lack of a least upper bound. It would seem that by imposing such an axiom or bound that you would lose the circular topology of the projective line - but perhaps I'm introducing more topology than is relevant to the initial question... I'm not sure